# Custom code in WordPress native gallery?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress native gallery;

```
[gallery ids="459,463,190,132,91"]
```

When editing the gallery, you can add a caption to the images in the gallery.  I want to add a button underneath the images in the gallery.  The button has it's own shortcode;

```
[wp_cart:Art 1:price:50.00:end]
```

How do i add the wp_cart shortcode to each image in the gallery caption?  Is there an option that let's you add custom code?

Comment: This needs to rewrite whole add_shortcode function for gallery to handle new args which holds buttons' data.

Comment: [add_filter and changing output captions of image gallery](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74675/12615)